# Dotnet Nuke Installation

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have been able to install DNN at my local machine, but after I run the default website the code asked me about the Database configuration in first step. When I proceed to the next step the progress is not exceeding from 15%. I have restarted the website many times but the progress stucks at this point and is not proceeding further. Is there anything which I need to be done before this step? Here is the second step in which I need help- [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database name, username and password as well as your instance name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've created your database first, and then given the user you are using  permissions to that database.

It's stopping on the install Database Schema, so it seems like your the Database user you are using may not have enough permissions.

*Put that user in the DBO role and also, (**TEMPORARILY**) give them sysadmin, serveradmin, and secruityadmin rights.  I do this, and then take it away AFTER the install.*

---

You can check out the installation guide if you have not yet: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Install_DotNetNuke

And, the DNN videos are very good:  http://www.dnnsoftware.com/videos